# foreign key constraint fails - hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, foreign-keys

I have problem when i try add data to table USERS. First my DB and classes.

DB structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admins` (
  `ADMIN_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `USERNAME` varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
  `PASSWORD` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `AUTHORITY` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ADMIN_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lecturers` (
  `LECTURER_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `SURNAME` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `TITLES` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `USERNAME` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `AUTHORITY` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `LEC_DESCRIPTION` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LECTURER_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=40;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `roles_name` (
  `role_id` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `authority` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `role_id` (`role_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `roles_name` (`role_id`, `authority`) VALUES
(1, 'ROLE_ADMIN'),
(2, 'ROLE_USER'),
(3, 'ROLE_LECTURER');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `USER_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `NAME` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `SURNAME` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `USER_DESCRIPTION` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `AUTHORITY` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ENABLED` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`USER_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=50000;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `roles_map` (
  `rm_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned,
  `admin_id` int(10) unsigned,
  `lecturer_id` int(10) unsigned,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rm_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`lecturer_id`) REFERENCES `lecturers` (`lecturer_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`admin_id`) REFERENCES `admins` (`admin_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles_name` (`role_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**RolesMap.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles_map")
public class RolesMap {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "RM_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int rm_id;
    //@Column(name = "USER_ID", unique = true)
    //private int user_id;
    @Column(name = "ADMIN_ID", unique = true)
    private int admin_id;
    @Column(name = "LECTURER_ID", unique = true)
    private int lecturer_id;
    @Column(name = "USERNAME", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int role_id;
    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

     //getters and setters

}
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int user_id;
    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "SURNAME", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String surname;
    @Column(name = "USERNAME", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username; // zamiast username
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "USER_DESCRIPTION", nullable = false)
    private String userDescription;
    @Column(name = "AUTHORITY", nullable = false)
    private String authority = "ROLE_USER";
    @Column(name = "ENABLED", nullable = false)
    private int enabled;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List <RolesMap> rolesMap;

      //getters and setters
}
```

**adding method**

```
public String addUser() {

    Session sess = null;

    try {
        sess = UserDao.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        sess.beginTransaction();
        RolesMap roles = new RolesMap();
        //roles.setrUser(user);
        User user = new User();
        roles.setPassword(getPassword());
        roles.setRole_id(2);
        roles.setUsername(getUsername());

        user.setName(getName());
        user.setSurname(getSurname());
        user.setUsername(getUsername());
        user.setPassword(getPassword());
        user.setUserDescription(getUserDescription());
        user.setAuthority(getAuthority());
        user.setEnabled(getEnabled());
        user.setRolesMap(new ArrayList<RolesMap>());
        user.getRolesMap().add(roles);
        sess.save(user);
        sess.getTransaction().commit();
        //getUserService().addUser(user);

        return SUCCESS;
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ERROR;
}
```

When I try use this method I have error:
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`soeOne2`.`roles_map`, CONSTRAINT `roles_map_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`lecturer_id`) REFERENCES `lecturers` (`LECTURER_ID`))

But I do not know why, because I'm trying to add data to the USER and ROLESMAP tables. I think when you add data to a table ROLESMAP/USER field lecturer_id and admin_id in ROLESMAP table shuld be NULL. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would normalize this a lot more than you have.  Then come back to the question.  For example, you duplicate username/password in 4 different tables.  Admin, Lecturer, and User are (as you've described) 3 different roles once a 'person using the system' has authenticated.  Usually, I use **user** as the root concept for an authenticated identity in a system.  Then apply roles (and additional attributes based on those roles via a new table(s), where necessary.  Authentication and Identity are one set of issues that ought to be handled separately through a conventional users table first.

Comment: If for example, you break out user as it's own concept, and then replace your current user with attendee or student(guessing what the user role is based on the presence of the lecturer role).  There should be no role map, unless it's this `rolemap : (unique_person_id, role_id )'.  In which case each value is a foreign key and the pair is the primary key and there are no nulls ever in this dataset.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `lecturer_id=0` is **NOT** `lecturer_id=null`.

Your application try to save `lecturer_id=0` and the database think that `0` is the ID of an item in table `lecturers`.

So the first workarround is to replace the `int` with `Integer`, so that you can assign `lecturer_id = null`

```
@Column(name = "LECTURER_ID", unique = true)
private Integer lecturer_id;
```

And I think you need this modification for all other references that work the same way.

---

The second point is, that the way you map references between entities is not the jpa (hibernate) way. I strongly recommend that you read something about mapping relations (OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToOne, ManyToMany) For example the Hibernate Reference [Chapter 7. Collection mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html) and [8. Association Mappings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/associations.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help. So I read something about the relationship mapping first.